# "It is not as if S+V" vs. "It is not as if S+ [subjunctive]"

Tags: phrase-usage, expressions, subjunctives

I'd like to know what feeling does this expression convey.

> *I'm surprised they've invited me to their wedding—**it's not as if** I know them well.*
>   (OED Learner's|[it's not as if](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/if_1#if_1__229))

Can you tell if the speaker is happy or unhappy for being invited to the ceremony from this sentence alone?

Does this assume any sarcastic tone if it's like this:

> *I'm surprised they've invited me to their wedding—**it's not as if** I **knew** them well.*

Does the tone of blaming and/or surprise get stronger if it's:

> *I'm surprised they've invited me to their wedding—**it's not as if** I **were** their old friend.*

I'm asking this question because the typical translation given for this phrase in my language has very much a nuance of sarcastic or looking down or chiding on the action or words that is remarked by this word.

Thank you! :)

Comment: Your first two examples remind me of, for example, *When they asked his nationality he said he **was** British* - where the speaker *might* use present tense, since obviously he's *still* British at time of utterance, but in practice we tend to switch to agreement with the tense of the primary verbs *(asked, said)*. The third example is a *subjunctive* usage that's increasingly going out of style today (we'd normally just use simple past ***was***, not ***were***). This choice of verb form has nothing to do with conveying sarcasm, disdain, or reproach in English.

Comment: @FumbleFingers  ...except insofar as a speaker who dares utter _"I were"_ will experience sarcasm, disdain, or reproach...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"It's not as if A is B" is a kind of "set phrase" which you can memorize as a whole.  The expression usually follows an unexpected or unusual result, because the ordinary conditions to create that situation don't exist.

> I'm surprised to hear he became a doctor.  *It's not as if* he was ever a very good student.
>
> Mary couldn't believe someone gave her flowers, since *it wasn't as if* she ordinarily [turned any heads.](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/turn_someone%27s_head).

In your example sentence, the speaker is at least mildly surprised, but otherwise there is no way to tell if it's a good or a bad surprise.

Answer (score 0):

I would always say it this way:

> "I'm surprised they've invited me to their wedding—it's not as if I
>   *knew* them well."

I don't think it's correct English to use **"know"** in this situation.  That doesn't mean that simple present indicative is always incorrect following **"as if"** or **"as though"**, but in this case, I think it should be in the past subjunctive **"knew"** form.

I would also not listen to the other people above who are telling you not to use **"were"** there and instead use **"was"**.  If you should choose to use "was" there, you will sound uneducated and stupid.  I would roll my eyes at you if you said "was" where they are saying it above just as I am rolling my eyes at them right now for even insinuating it.  Yes, a lot of native speakers do use "was" in your situations, but it's incorrect grammar or, at the very least, informal.

There is no change in meaning above; all of those examples are pretty sarcastic since you're telling someone this anyway.  It could be understood as not being sarcastic, but it would depend on context clues.  I would read it as your being surprised and almost mocking the invitation, but you could just as well be stating a fact.